# Set the reason on a HttpResponse in ASP.NET Core from middlware

Tags: http, asp.net-core, .net-core

How can I set the reason phrase on a HTTP response in ASP.NET Core from some middleware?

In previous versions (full framework), I would do the following:

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
context.Response.ReasonPhrase = "Missing or invalid token.";
```

In ASP.NET Core, the only property available is the `StatusCode`.

Here is an example of a Fiddler capture with a custom reason set on the response.

[image: Example of a reason sent from ASP.NET WebAPI (full framework)]

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place? Any reasons beyond debugging?

Comment: @JulianReschke Because this is an API, and the status code isn't always enough to convey meaning, and sending additional content via the body and header isn't always appropriate.

Comment: Then you're in trouble, because HTTP/2 doesn't have reason phrases.

Comment: @Kieron Tried the accepted answer with .net core 2.1 but it returns `200 OK` expecting the custom message like `200 Information retrieved successfully`. I am using PostMan

Comment: where does `context` comes from ?

Comment: @GuidoG That's the `HttpContext`.

Comment: @Kieron I am new to ASP.NET Core, where exact do I get this HttpContext in my IActionResult ?

Comment: @GuidoG that interface has a method called `ExecuteResultAsync` which has an `ActionContext` as a parameter. That in turn has the `HttpContext` as a property.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
context.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "Missing or invalid token.";
```

Comment: Note that HTTP/2 doesn't have reason phrases, so you're depending on something that might not be available when you deploy.

Comment: Hi, @DarinDimitrov Tried this with `.net core 2.1` but it returns `200 OK` not the custom message like `200 Information retrieved succcssfully`. I am using PostMan

Comment: Any reason why not `context.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>()`? (skipping the ".Response.HttpContext" bit)