# Custom HTTP Status's description without body's content

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to place a customer description for HTTP Status Code instead of using its default description. For example, the below image returned "403 Forbidden". I want to change it to "403 Unexpected Error" without body's content. The same go to Status Code 204 which my program expect a custom description.

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jTDJ.png)

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost("riskProfile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CustomerRiskProfile([FromBody] CustomerRiskProfileRequest request)
{
    var response = await _mediator.Send(request);
    if(response.Code == Result.Forbidden.Value)
    {
        return StatusCode(403, string.Empty);
    }

    return StatusCode(204, string.Empty);
}
```

Do you guys have any idea to make the app display the intended result? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the reason on a HttpResponse in ASP.NET Core from middlware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039003/set-the-reason-on-a-httpresponse-in-asp-net-core-from-middlware)

Answer (score 0):

These http status codes are an RFC standard. These codes have a fixed meaning. According to `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages` the response status line transmits the status code and message. I do not know a way in .net core web api to change the text for a code.
But better consider reading the status code in your front end app and then show a localized message appropriate for the status code. That's a better way. Or what is your motive?